# Bind WPF control to public object

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, controls

I have a UserControl with some public objects that I want to bind in the WPF controls:

```
public partial class UINewCheck : UserControl
{
    private CheckServiceClient checkService = new CheckServiceClient();
    public Bank bank = new Bank();
    public BankBranchOffice bankBranchOffice = new BankBranchOffice();

    public UINewCheck()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Then I have two textboxes, one for the Bank name and another one for the bank branch office locality.

What I want is to bind one textbox with bank.Name and the other one with bankBranchOffice.Locality.

I tried creating two static resources in the usercontrol with the same name, but when I do the binding like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <dm:Bank x:Key="bank" />
    <dm:BankBranchOffice x:Key="bankBranchOffice" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

...

```
<TextBox Name="tbxBankBranchOffice" Width="200" IsReadOnly="True">
     <Binding Source="{StaticResource bankBranchOffice}" Path="Locality" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" />
</TextBox>
```

I just dont get the value when it updates so its not doing the binding correctly.

So, how can I bind the text of the TextBox with a public defined object? Remember that I have more than one object to bind.

Comment: Do you have a good book or tutorial on this? Because you have a few misconceptions about how this works, but it's really not something that can be put in a short SO post.

Comment: Really? I thought I was in the correct track. Somebody once told me in SO that I have to declare an object as public to bind it. I´m a service and database programmer actually, so I´m trying to do a small app with WPF. I have watch some good tutorials but I guess that wasnt enought. Can you recommend me any good tutorial on this?

Comment: A couple of those misconceptions: 1) you need a public **property** to bind to (you have members, not properties).  2) you have declared additional instances as static resources.  3) normally you would set  the view model as `DataContext` rather than as static resources.  ... That said, I'm not quite sure why your binding isn't working, it looks correct if unorthodox.

Comment: I got it. I used TextBox.DataContext now. It wasnt working because when I get the bank using the service, I assign to bank a new object. bank = new bank { ... }; I just needed to update the DataContext there. I will publish the answer then. Thanks @McGarnagle.